# Index an array using a const member variable

Tags: c++, arrays, class, indexing

I have the following class. I want to use the member `size` as an index of an `arr1` that I will fill in the constructor. However, compiler doesn't compile and says that a "variable-sized object cannot be initialized". How is this possible if `size` is a const?

On the other hand, `arr2` is correctly filled by using `siz`.

```
class myclass {
public:
    myclass() 
    {        
        int arr1[size] = { 1, 2 };

        const size_t siz = 2;
        int arr2[siz] { 1, 2 };
    };

    const size_t size = 2;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since index, really meaning size, is a non-static, non-constexpr, class member its value will not be known until initialization. What you need in your case is a compile time constant. You could resolve this in a few different ways, examples

```
class myclass {
  enum { SIZE = 2 };  // this
 public:
  static constexpr size_t kSize = 2;  // or that
  myclass() : size(2) {
    int arr1[SIZE] = { 1, 2 };
    int arr2[kSize] = { 1, 2 };
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

Just remember that static class members are allocated in a way that every class instantiation sees the same value and if public are visible without instantiation. Also, every static variable within a function body is allocated in a way that every invocation of such function sees the most current value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you can change it in the constructor:

```
myclass() : index(3)
{
    //...
}
```

you just default initialized the const member.

you have no reason for not using **`std::Vector`** here.

---

you can get it working by making it static(bad idea):

```
static const size_t index = 2;
```

PS.`index` is bad name here, you mean size of the array not an index to it.

Comment: Ok, so the member can be modified in the constructor. But, as long as I know, the way I initialized that member works the same as the way you initialized it in the constructor. Also, I can't see how can that member be modified at run-time, so it should work, I think. Thank you. Vector looks like a better option, but I wondered why this didn't work. PS. The member's name has been modified.

Comment: @AnselmoGPP the fact that you can change it in construction, makes it variable. think of this: `myclass(size_t ic) : index(ic)`. it is run time constant. you have just promised to not to change it when it is initialized